# matplotlib- 2 legends in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

I have the following piece of code:

```
plt.subplot2grid(shape=(2,3),loc=(0,0))
df.Survived.value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind="bar",alpha=0.6,color= ['b','r'])
plt.title("Bar Representation- Survived wrt Age")
plt.xlabel("Survived")
plt.ylabel("Percentage")
plt.show()
```

The graph looks like this :

[image]

I just wanted to add 2 legends on the upper right hand side of the bar graph, Survived and Died. Just like in this graph: [Graph](http://www.academis.eu/posts/images/matplotlib_barchart.png)

Also, I wanted to make the labels 0 and 1 vertically aligned.

Comment: Do you mean two separate legend boxes?

Comment: Yes, two seperate legend boxes. Like this one: http://www.academis.eu/posts/images/matplotlib_barchart.png

Comment: Are you ploting the french flag ?

Comment: Haha. No, I'm a newbie in data science and solving the Titanic challenge on Kaggle. I was just visualizing the data and was curious how to add legends.

Comment: @DavidG No, this question is not a duplicate of the question you mentioned. I checked that post before posting this question, but it is not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: So the actual answer to my first question was you only want one legend box with 2 entries in it

Comment: Can you please just answer my question?

Comment: The example you link to only has one legend box, @Ronith, although it has two data series described in that box. Terminology confusion. There's an [anatomy of matplotlib plots](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#parts-of-a-figure) for background, but all you need is the [`legend()` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html).